# How can I resolve this nmcli issue?

Tags: vpn, archlinux, dbus, pptp, nmcli

I created a vpn profile using nm-connection-editor then i use `nmcli conn up id PJATK` PJATK(is the name of the VPN connection). In return, I get

```
Error: Connection activation failed: Unknown reason
Hint: use 'journalctl -xe NM_CONNECTION=d894277c-632a-42c8-844b-96ef586c58ab + NM_DEVICE=wlp0s20f3' to get more details.
```

When I run `journalctl -xe NM_CONNECTION=d894277c-632a-42c8-844b-96ef586c58ab + NM_DEVICE=wlp0s20f3` I get this:

```
Dec 14 09:38:17 archlinux NetworkManager[613]: <info>  [1671007097.8926] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Dec 14 09:38:18 archlinux NetworkManager[613]: <info>  [1671007098.1032] device (wlp0s20f3): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to F6:E2:86:D4:0B:D7 (scanning)
Dec 14 09:38:18 archlinux NetworkManager[613]: <info>  [1671007098.3756] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: internal-starting -> disconnected
Dec 14 09:38:18 archlinux NetworkManager[613]: <info>  [1671007098.3763] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 14 09:38:21 archlinux NetworkManager[613]: <info>  [1671007101.4587] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: starting connection 'UPC507959656' (b42ef2cb-61a6-4354-81cf-be67779b6d6c)
Dec 14 09:38:21 archlinux NetworkManager[613]: <info>  [1671007101.4588] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 14 09:38:21 archlinux NetworkManager[613]: <info>  [1671007101.4602] device (wlp0s20f3): set-hw-addr: reset MAC address to 38:FC:98:5B:F2:DE (preserve)
Dec 14 09:38:21 archlinux NetworkManager[613]: <info>  [1671007101.4609] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 14 09:38:21 archlinux NetworkManager[613]: <info>  [1671007101.4612] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) access point 'UPC507959656' has security, but secrets are required.
Dec 14 09:38:21 archlinux NetworkManager[613]: <info>  [1671007101.4612] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 14 09:38:21 archlinux NetworkManager[613]: <info>  [1671007101.4614] sup-iface[d93b7494ebf16bd0,0,wlp0s20f3]: wps: type pbc start...
Dec 14 09:38:21 archlinux NetworkManager[613]: <info>  [1671007101.4623] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 14 09:38:21 archlinux NetworkManager[613]: <info>  [1671007101.4626] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 14 09:38:21 archlinux NetworkManager[613]: <info>  [1671007101.4629] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) connection 'UPC507959656' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Dec 14 09:38:21 archlinux NetworkManager[613]: <info>  [1671007101.5446] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
Dec 14 09:38:21 archlinux NetworkManager[613]: <info>  [1671007101.5711] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Dec 14 09:38:21 archlinux NetworkManager[613]: <info>  [1671007101.5895] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Dec 14 09:38:21 archlinux NetworkManager[613]: <info>  [1671007101.6022] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
Dec 14 09:38:21 archlinux NetworkManager[613]: <info>  [1671007101.9934] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
Dec 14 09:38:21 archlinux NetworkManager[613]: <info>  [1671007101.9935] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "UPC50795965>
Dec 14 09:38:21 archlinux NetworkManager[613]: <info>  [1671007101.9936] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 14 09:38:21 archlinux NetworkManager[613]: <info>  [1671007101.9939] dhcp4 (wlp0s20f3): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Dec 14 09:38:23 archlinux NetworkManager[613]: <info>  [1671007103.0374] dhcp4 (wlp0s20f3): state changed new lease, address=192.168.1.77
Dec 14 09:38:23 archlinux NetworkManager[613]: <info>  [1671007103.0672] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 14 09:38:23 archlinux NetworkManager[613]: <info>  [1671007103.0712] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 14 09:38:23 archlinux NetworkManager[613]: <info>  [1671007103.0716] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 14 09:38:23 archlinux NetworkManager[613]: <info>  [1671007103.0736] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: successful, device activated.
Dec 14 09:39:14 archlinux NetworkManager[613]: <info>  [1671007154.2239] vpn[0x556cbb96a160,d894277c-632a-42c8-844b-96ef586c58ab,"PJATK"]: starting sstp
Dec 14 09:39:14 archlinux NetworkManager[613]: <warn>  [1671007154.4751] vpn[0x556cbb96a160,d894277c-632a-42c8-844b-96ef586c58ab,"PJATK"]: dbus: failure: connect-failed (1)
Dec 14 09:39:38 archlinux NetworkManager[613]: <info>  [1671007178.6187] vpn[0x556cbb96a3e0,d894277c-632a-42c8-844b-96ef586c58ab,"PJATK"]: starting sstp
Dec 14 09:39:38 archlinux NetworkManager[613]: <warn>  [1671007178.8895] vpn[0x556cbb96a3e0,d894277c-632a-42c8-844b-96ef586c58ab,"PJATK"]: dbus: failure: connect-failed (1)
Dec 14 09:42:52 archlinux NetworkManager[613]: <info>  [1671007372.3769] vpn[0x556cbb96a660,d894277c-632a-42c8-844b-96ef586c58ab,"PJATK"]: starting sstp
Dec 14 09:42:52 archlinux NetworkManager[613]: <warn>  [1671007372.6223] vpn[0x556cbb96a660,d894277c-632a-42c8-844b-96ef586c58ab,"PJATK"]: dbus: failure: connect-failed (1)
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.